# Resetting JQuery function when window resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/7dreho2b/11/)

I am currently using slick-slider to display content in 3 columns. I am doing this using (flexbox) Essentially - I only want the slider to be activated on mobile view, therefore when the users shrink(resize) the screen down to mobile view the flexbox 3 columns turn into a slider, displaying one slide at a time.

The problem I am having when the user opens the screen back to desktop view, the slides do not come back up, they seem to get lost in the slider on mobile view.

what I want to happen is for it to wait until the user has resized the screen to 649 then when it resizes back to 651 it unslicks

```
$(slider).slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 800,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3,
  speed: 800,
  responsive: [{
   breakpoint: 1024,
   settings: {
   slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   infinite: true,
   dots: true
   }
  }, {
   breakpoint: 650,
   settings: {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
    }
  }],
});

 $(window).on('resize', function() {
  var win = $(this);
  if (win.width() >= 650) {
$(slider).slick('unslick')
 };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe unslick() is the right function.

```
$(slider).unslick();
```

Comment: on the second to bottom line?

Comment: Yes. instead of $(slider).slick('unslick'); try $(slider).unslick();